# an article he wrote

Tags: meaning, clauses, ambiguity

a. He showed me an article which he wrote last night and which was about whales.

Could 'last night' modify 'showed'?

Could the sentence mean:
Last night he showed me an article which he wrote and which was about whales.

I know that (a) is an awkward sentence, but I think it is grammatical. I want to see if it is ambiguous. To me it seems that 'last night' can only modify 'wrote', but I am not sure about that.

Many thanks.

Comment: No, he wrote it last night, adverbial phrase: When he wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

If someone uses '... wrote last night ...' in a sentence, then the sentence indicates the time that it was written. If they meant that something else happened last night, they need to construct the sentence differently. It isn't ambiguous.